# How to get text value of an anchor href generated by javascript?

Tags: javascript, ruby, selenium, web-scraping, nokogiri

While scraping an extranet platform (with login so I cannot put the link here) I met this guys:

```
<td body>
<tr goto="javascript:prddetailrech(651438,'')" style="cursor:pointer;"><td valign="top" id="colREF"><a href="javascript:prddetailrech(651438,'');">C002</a></td>
```

This is the first  of many and I need this reference : COO2.

This is my code, after entering the platform with selenium I use nokogiri (only because I know it better)

```
driver.get 'http://riviera.prescripteurs.axessia.net/common/code/b2c/prd_b2c.asp?prd_PageSize=200'
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(driver.page_source)
appartments = []
rows = doc.css('tbody tr')
sleep 7
rows.each do |row|
  ref = row.css('colREF nobr a href').text
  appartment_info = {
    reference: ref
  }
  p appartments << appartment_info
```

And I get many {:reference=>""} in an array.
Any insight on how I could get this value with nokogiri or selenium (ruby)?
I would appreciate any feedback.

Answer (score 1):

`row.css('colREF nobr a href')` is not the correct CSS selector.

`colREF` is an *ID*, not an HTML *element*, so you would access it with `#colREF`.

`href` is an *attribute*, not an HTML *element*. You can't extract attribute values directly with the CSS selector but can use Nokogiri's `.attributes` method instead:

```
ref = row.css('#colREF a').attributes["href"].value
```

*note* I would recommend touching up on CSS selectors, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking the time to explain and for the doc, gonna catch up on this !

Comment: hey, Im still struggling, alway get undefined method attributes for[] I tried also different way doesnt work either. Did I miss something above, doc = Nokogiri::HTML(driver.page_source) is right? i use driver.page_source to make the link with Selenium.  Thank you

Comment: I tried this as well ref = row.xpath('//td[@id="colREF"]/a/@href').text and it give me an array with many javascript:prddetailrech(728694,''), this (728694 doesnt appear on the page but has something to do with strSQL, I see it when I inspect

Comment: Running the page source through Nokogiri is **not** the same as running JS commands in Selenium. The reason is that Selenium will execute the Javascript on the page and in many cases this is required for the page to load the data properly.

Comment: Thank you, will try with Selenium then!